# How to solve the equation $\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kC_{n}^{k}\cos{k\theta}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find all real numbers $x$, such that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kC_{n}^{k}\cos{ka}=0$$

My idea: we can find this value
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kC_{n}^{k}\cos{ka}.$$

use Elur $e^{ikx}=\cos{kx}+i\sin{kx}\Longrightarrow 2\cos{2kx}=e^{ikx}+e^{-ikx}$,
$$2x^kC_{n}^{k}\cos{ka}=((e^{ia}x)^k+(e^{-ia}x)^k]C_{n}^{k}$$

so
$$2\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^kC_{n}^{k}\cos{ka}=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}(xe^{ia})^kC_{n}^{k}+(xe^{-ia})^{k}C_{n}^{k}=(xe^{ia}+1)^n+(xe^{-ia}+1)^n$$

Comment: Hint: $e^{i\theta}=\cos \theta+i\sin\theta$ may be helpful.

Comment: yes,I try it,But I failure

Comment: Too bad: if either the $\,k\,$ of $\,x\,$ or that of $\,\cos\,$ was $\,n-k\,$ I could come up with a pretty simple, quick solution

Comment: Please clarify your question, are you assuming $x$ and $\theta$ are related?

Comment: $x$ and $\theta$ is not related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's calculate 
$$
\sum x^k C_n^k\cos k\theta =\mathfrak{Re} \sum C_n^k x^k e^{ik\theta}=\mathfrak{Re}(1+xe^{i\theta})^n.
$$
If $\mathfrak{Re}(1+xe^{i\theta})^n=0$, then
$$
\mathfrak{Arg}(1+xe^{i\theta})^n=\pm \frac{1}{2}\pi,\\
\mathfrak{Arg}(1+xe^{i\theta})=\frac{2k+1}{2n}\pi,
$$
the rest is easy. You can show that when and only when
$$
2\theta-\pi=\frac{2k+1}{2n}\pi,
$$
you have a real solution 
$$
x=2\sin \frac{2k+1}{2n}\pi.
$$

Comment: @O.L. Oh, it should be Real.

Comment: then $x=?$ Thank you,